# Adjusting code to account for another reading type

Tags: java, compiler-errors, indexoutofboundsexception

I'm adjusting a class in my Java code to account for another int, here is the new one:

```
class Card {
    private String name;
    private int price;
    private int profit;

    public Card(String name, int price, int profit) {
        this.name = name;
        this.price = price;
        this.profit = profit;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public int getPrice() {
        return price;
    }

    public int getProfit() {
        return profit;
    }
}
```

initislly public Card only read String name and int price, and had profit = price to just more simpler cases, how do I adjust this snippet of the code for all to go well? I've been stuck here for quite some time:

```
private static List<Problem> readProblems(String priceFilePath) throws IOException {
        List<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<>();

        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(priceFilePath));

        while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
            int numCards = scanner.nextInt();
            int maxMoney = scanner.nextInt();
            scanner.nextLine();

            List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
                String[] cardInfo = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
                String cardName = cardInfo[0];
                int cardPrice = Integer.parseInt(cardInfo[1]);
                cards.add(new Card(cardName, cardPrice));
            }

            problems.add(new Problem(cards, maxMoney));
        }

        scanner.close();
        return problems;
    }
```

I tried this new snippet:

```
private static List<Problem> readProblems(String priceFilePath) throws IOException {
    List<Problem> problems = new ArrayList<>();

    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(new File(priceFilePath));

    while (scanner.hasNextLine()) {
        int numCards = scanner.nextInt();
        int maxMoney = scanner.nextInt();
        scanner.nextLine(); // Move to the next line

        List<Card> cards = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i = 0; i < numCards; i++) {
            String[] cardInfo = scanner.nextLine().split(" ");
            String cardName = cardInfo[0];
            int cardPrice = Integer.parseInt(cardInfo[1]);
            int cardProfit = Integer.parseInt(cardInfo[2]); // Add profit from input
            cards.add(new Card(cardName, cardPrice, cardProfit));
        }

        problems.add(new Problem(cards, maxMoney));
    }

    scanner.close();
    return problems;
}
```

then i got this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 2
        at Algo.readProblems(Algo.java:53)
        at Algo.main(Algo.java:15)
```

tried debugging more by adding some error handling and a print statement to get the stack trace in case of an exception. Idea being it will help identify where the issue might be occurring, but to no avail

would appreciate any help on this

Comment: the issue is, you are trying to get the third element of an array that contains maximum two elements

Comment: @Stultuske just skimmed through that, i have strict inequality here i < numCards to prvent that, what else do i need to fix?

Comment: your i < numCards prevents nothing, since that 2 is hardcoded.

Comment: Have you changed the price file to include the profit as the third item on the line? (Obviously, you haven't.)

Comment: How is 'profit' *not* determined by calculation?

Comment: @DavidConrad mind expanding on that? what am i supposed to change?

Comment: @g00se how profit is calculated when the output file computes it in order to print it out

Comment: *@g00se how profit is calculated when the output file computes it in order to print it out* Then there is something funny going on: `Card` has three parameters to its ctor and one of them is `profit` and that's INput

Comment: The code used to expect the file to contain two values on each line, the name and price. Now it expects three values on each line, name, price, and profit. Has the input file been changed to add that third item on each line for the cards?